# ElasticAPM Couldn't establish connection to APM Server: "#Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument>" elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apm

```
[ElasticAPM] Couldn't establish connection to APM Server:
"#<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument>"
```

While connecting to APM server, the above errors keeps on rendering in the development server console.